# cant get Azure Domain Service to work, it is stuck at pending

Tags: azure

I am testing Azure AD Domain service.

I tried to turn on the AD Domain Service but after turning it on, it seems that it is stuck at "Pending". It has done that for 12 hour now....anyone got any Idea?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can check history status of Azure Active Directory domain service here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/ to see whether during the time you enabled, Microsoft was doing its maintenance. Pending setup of your virtual network would be another reason.

If the environment is not production, I'd highly recommend to disable the Domain service, create a new VNET then associate the new VNET to Domain service.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we should check **DNS domain name**:
**1**. **Can't** create an Azure Domain Services domain with a domain prefix longer than 15 characters.
**2**. Ensure that the DNS domain name you have chosen for the managed domain does **not** already exist in the virtual network. Specifically, check if:
**a**.you already have a domain with the same DNS domain name on the virtual network.
**b**.the virtual network you've selected has a VPN connection with your on-premises network and you have a domain with the same DNS domain name on your on-premises network.
**c**.you have an existing cloud service with that name on the virtual network.
Also we should check **virtual network** settings:
**a**.Ensure that the virtual network you have specified belongs to an Azure region supported by Azure AD Domain Services. Refer to the Azure services by region page to know the Azure regions in which Azure AD Domain Services is available.
**b**.Virtual networks belonging to a region where Azure AD Domain Services is not supported do not show up in the drop-down list.
**c**.Use a dedicated subnet within the virtual network for Azure AD Domain Services. Ensure you do not select the gateway subnet. See networking considerations.
**d**.Similarly, virtual networks that were created using Azure Resource Manager do not appear in the drop-down list. Resource Manager-based virtual networks are not currently supported by Azure AD Domain Services.

More information about enable Azure AD Domain Services, refer to the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started-enableaadds).

Comment: Thanks I will check this, I will get back to everyone at the weeked